# using encryption org.jasypt.encryption on android produces error

Tags: java, android, encryption, dalvik, jasypt

I am trying to write an app to encrypt passwords using jasypt encryption jar. when calling

```
     String text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"; 
     StandardPBEByteEncryptor encryptor=new StandardPBEByteEncryptor();     
     encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES"); 
     encryptor.setPassword("HelloWorld");      
     byte[] encrypted=encryptor.encrypt(text.getBytes());
```

it produces the error message:

```
    dalvikvm VFY: unable to resolve static field 4 (NFC) in Lcom/ibm/icu/text/Normalizer;
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Something is attempting to use a class that isn't present at run time. Can you show the full error from logcat in your question?

Answer (score 0):

here what I have:

```
   10-05 13:40:01.005 8202 8202 D     dalvikvm                                     DexOpt: load 13ms, verify+opt 36ms, 283628 bytes
   10-05 13:40:02.975 8368 8368 D     dalvikvm ree.encrypt                         Late-enabling CheckJNI
   10-05 13:40:03.160 8368 8368 I     System.out ree.encrypt                       Text = [84, 104, 101, 32, 113, 117, 105, 99, 107, 32, 98, 114, 111, 119, 110, 32, 102, 111,     120, 32, 106, 117, 109, 112, 115, 32, 111, 118, 101, 114, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 108, 97, 122, 121, 32, 100, 111, 103]
   10-05 13:40:03.160 8368 8368 I     System.out ree.encrypt                       start *****
   10-05 13:40:03.160 8368 8368 W     dalvikvm ree.encrypt                         VFY: unable to resolve static field 4 (NFC) in Lcom/ibm/icu/text/Normalizer;
   10-05 13:40:03.160 8368 8368 D     dalvikvm ree.encrypt                         VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d
   10-05 13:40:03.200 8368 8368 I     System.out ree.encrypt                       stop *****
   10-05 13:40:03.240 8368 8368 D     libEGL ree.encrypt                           loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
   10-05 13:40:03.245 8368 8368 D     libEGL ree.encrypt                           loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
   10-05 13:40:03.250 8368 8368 D     libEGL ree.encrypt                           loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
   10-05 13:40:03.255 8368 8368 D      ree.encrypt                                 Device driver API match
   10-05 13:40:03.255 8368 8368 D      ree.encrypt                                 Device driver API version: 10
   10-05 13:40:03.255 8368 8368 D      ree.encrypt                                 User space API version: 10
   10-05 13:40:03.255 8368 8368 D      ree.encrypt                                 mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012
   10-05 13:40:03.290 8368 8368 D     OpenGLRenderer ree.encrypt                   Enabling debug mode 0
```

here the code:

```
    System.out.println("start *****");

     String text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"; 
     StandardPBEByteEncryptor encryptor=new StandardPBEByteEncryptor();     
     encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES"); 
     encryptor.setPassword("HelloWorld");      
     byte[] encrypted=encryptor.encrypt(text.getBytes()); 

    System.out.println("stop *****");
```

thanks